# Pandas data from stdin

Tags: python, json, pandas, stdin

Is it possible to have stdin data go into a pandas DataFrame?

Currently I'm saving the data in an intermediate `json` file and then doing:

```
pandas.read_json('my_json_file.json')
```

but was wondering if it's possible to pipe the stdin directly in the python script.
I found this: [How to read from stdin or from a file if no data is piped in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264991/how-to-read-from-stdin-or-from-a-file-if-no-data-is-piped-in-python)
but not sure how to do a line-by-line insertion in a pandas DF.

Comment: Person after my own heard. The bash shell provides so much functionality free and these monolithic programs reinvent the wheel (inferiorly).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use the `sys.stdin` as a `file` object (which it actually is) and pass it to `pandas` `read_xy` method.

```
$ cat test.py
import sys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(sys.stdin)
print df

$ cat data.json
{"a": [1,2,3,4], "b":[3,4,5,6]}

$ python test.py < data.json
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  6
```

Comment: For python3, write `print(df)`

Comment: Do you ever feel guilty how easy python is, like we're cheating? :D

Comment: For anyone who wants to use csv instead, it's as easy as changing it to `read_csv(...)`