# Python - stdin - how to recognize the source of the input?

Tags: python, stdin

I am looking for a way how to determine whether `stdin` input comes from another application by piping or not.

Let say that I have a program that **either accepts the input data from piped stdin** (when you pipe it from another application - grep, tail, ...) **or it uses a default data file**. I don't want the user to fill in manually the data when prompted because there was no stdin piped.

My simple code example looks like this:

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
    print line
```

When I run the script using this:

```
echo "data" | python example.py
```

I get

```
data
```

and the script ends.

While if I run the script in the following way,

```
python example.py
```

it prompts user to fill in the input and it waits.

Therefore I am looking for something like follows to avoid the prompt when no data are piped.

```
from sys import stdin

if is_stdin_piped():
    for line in stdin:
        print line
else:
    print "default"
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use input redirection, the standard input is not connected to a terminal like it usually is. You can check if a file descriptor is connected to a terminal or not with the `isatty` function:

```
import os

def is_stdin_piped():
    return not os.isatty(0)
```

For extra safety use `sys.stdin.fileno()` instead of `0`.

**Update:** To check if stdin is redirected from a file (rather than another program, such as an IDE or a shell pipeline) you can use `fstat`:

```
import os, stat

def is_stdin_a_file():
    status = os.fstat(0)
    return stat.S_ISREG(status.st_mode)
```

Comment: It looks good and it does almost what I need. When I run it from the command line, everythin is working well. However, when I run it in PyDev IDE (therefore no piping) the is_stdin_piped() returns as it was piped. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Your IDE uses a pipe without you knowing it. But hold on - there's a way to check if the input is redirected from a file.